# How to prove Quicksort is O(n*lg n) with special conditions?

Tags: performance, big-o, quicksort

This is one the questions on my Data Structures homework:

Suppose that we have a linear-time procedure that is guaranteed to find a pivot element for Quicksort such that
at least 1% of the array is less than or equal to the pivot and at least 1% is greater than or equal to the pivot.
Show that Quicksort will then have worst-case complexity O(n lg n).

I know that worst-case complexity for quicksort in general is O(n^2). I read that this happens when all the values of the pivot chosen is either the largest or smallest of the taken set.

My guess is that, because of the given condition that at least 1% of the array be bigger and at least 1% of the array be smaller than the pivot, this eliminates the situation where the pivot is the smallest or largest element in the set. Thus it can never be O(n^2)

Does this sound correct?

Comment: @MitchWheat How naive?  No medians in pivot selection?

Comment: @John: naïve == vanilla == no median.

Answer (score 0):

The main clincher in this type of problem is showing that there are only O(log(n)) steps.

Ideal quicksort recursion is

```
T(N) = 2T(N/2) + O(n)
```

Which we can easily show by the master theorem to be O(NlogN).

The O(n) term is a factor at every level of the recursion tree; additionally, all elements must be processed at every level in the ideal case; even though technically, most elements will make it much farther down the recursion tree than others, we can assume without asymptotic loss that a "worst-case scenario" will happen and all elements are processed at every level. Thus, all we must do is prove that there are at most O(log(N)) steps in the recursion tree under your given assumption.

Quicksort recursion given your assumption:

```
T(N) = T(N/100) + T(99N/100) + O(n).
```

We can assume WLOG that once there are 99 or fewer elements in a single branch of the recursion tree, only a constant number of operations at most will happen to sort them (thus, O(1) * O(n) = O(n) operations occurring at the bottom level; the recursion tree neither shrinks nor grows).

So, how do we prove the maximum number of steps in the entire tree? Well, we follow the unluckiest element(s)! Assume we start with N elements. Given our assumptions, there should be somewhere between 50 and 99 elements that form the largest branch of the final step of the level of the recursion tree we actually care about. The worst-case operations they've received to get that far all being part of the 99%.

So, we have at most 99 elements formed by X iterations of being cut by 1%. This should look like a different recursion tree you should've seen before, namely, the "geometrically decreasing" tree. As for the math:

```
99 = N*(.99)^X
99/N = (1/.99)^-X
(1/.99)^X = N/99
log_(1/.99) (1/.99)^X = log_(1/.99) N/99
X = log_(1/.99) N/99
```

And as you can see, the term on the right is O(log(N)). So this is the maximum number of levels of recursion, each of which do at most O(N) work, so the total work is O(Nlog(N)).

I'm not sure if you want more rigor than that (explaining real recursion proofs from scratch is a lot of work), but this would be acceptable for most universities....